# port 8000 not enable even after enable it on firewall Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, flask, tcp, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

I'm stuck with a strange behavior with ubuntu 18 into digital ocean, I just created a droplet and didn't use DO firewall but try to enable port 8000 into server, like this:

`sudo ufw allow 8000/tcp`

When I check my port rules its ok, I mean its really what I need, there's even more (cause I also added udp)

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/udp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8000/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/udp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I run a flask service using port 8000 into server, something like this:

`FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000`

I can get a response inside server, eg:

`curl 127.0.0.1:8000`

But when I try to do the same thing out site, I got refused connection, eg:

`curl IPSERVER:8000`

response:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to IPSERVER port 8000: Connection refused`

I also check the port status using this service: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

And it says that port 8000 is closed, but I enabled it and there's no firewall on DO (I have one but I removed to test and it still not working)

Does anyone know what could be? Ubuntu 18 has a another place to enable it? Should I restart the server before made these changes?

Comment: Try using `--host=<your public ip>`

Comment: Well done, you're right, it works I thought that using a localhost I'll can access externally. Feel free to add it into responses to I vote up. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your script with;

`--host=<your public ip>` if you want to bind to just the address specified.

`--host=0.0.0.0` to bind to all available addresses.

`--host=127.0.0.1` will only bind to the loop-back address.

The [Quick Start](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) docs states;

> Externally Visible Server
>
> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only
>   accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network.
>   This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the
>   application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> $ flask run --host=0.0.0.0
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.